# Properly resize Jetpack Compose Material3 SearchBar

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-material3, android-jetpack-compose-ui

I am using the SearchBar from `androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.2.0-alpha10` and have made it smaller in height unsing `Modifier`. The problem is that it does not scale properly and I end up cutting off the query (and placeholder) text.

[image]
[image]

Is it possible to maintain the smaller height and customize the height of the text input?